# Can I use SAP SQL Anywhere (Sybase) with Entity Framework in .net core 2?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, sqlanywhere

I'm migrating a project in web forms to .net core 2.0 and I have to use SQL Anywhere (Sybase) as a database, can I use SQL anywhere with entity framework in the .net core?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation on EF Core, it does not look as if Sybase is supported.

You can see the list of Database Providers available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/